# Constructors and object's member variable initializiation

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code:

```
struct Car{

public:
     Car(){}
     Car(int w, int d){
         wheels = w;
         doors = d;
     }
private:
     int wheels;
     int doors;
};

int main(){
     Car *cars = new Car[10];
     cars[0] = {4, 4};
     cars[1] = Car(4, 4);
}
```

Considering the struct allows no way of setting the value of wheels and doors other than using a constructor, which would be the better way to assign values to the array of cars? Is there any difference between the last two lines in the above code?

I am currently working on a hash table implementation for school and the starting base of c++ code provided has a Key-Value pair class with only a setKey method and no setValue method. So I am basically having to assign values with calls to a constructor and am not sure if there is a difference between using {} or *classname*(Key, Value) for assignment.

Comment: Both of your assignment methods are the same, for this class. It might differ if you had overloaded non-copy `operator=`, or an `initializer_list` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In this case both the ways are same because ultimately `copy-assignment` operator of `Car` will be invoked which is supplied by compiler by default.

If your purpose is just to allocate some objects of `Car` and initialize them with some initial default value then why not use `std::vector` in this case,

```
std::vector<Car> cars(10, Car(4,4));
```

But above method will not allocate memory on heap but you might consider it.